# Which windows event is triggered on secondary display device detection

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

This question is specific to Windows 8.1.

I want to schedule a windows task to run when a secondary output device (e.g., VGA monitor or HDMI A/V receiver is turned on or off) but I'm not sure which event should be used for this. I found something related to network cable plug/unplug here https://superuser.com/questions/262799/how-to-launch-a-command-on-network-connection-disconnection , but nothing for external audio/video devices. Any such event or events exist? If not, any other way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your computer has no way of knowing if the "secondary output device" is turned on/off. Your machine only knows if a display is plugged in or not to the video port on the computer.

Comment: Well, the display driver or other windows components must somehow know that the device connected to the HDMI port is turned on or off, e.g., by reading the EDID, otherwise it won't be able, for example, to automatically extend the display to the secondary device. Whether there's an event that's triggered by this action or not is my question.

Comment: I suppose I misunderstood. Have you tried contacting Microsoft or browsing their [forums](http://support.microsoft.com/product/windows/windows-8-1)?

[This](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8a9b5aa7-fe33-4e6d-b39b-8ac80a21fdc2/disable-monitor-off-detection-how?forum=w7itprogeneral) is the closest I could come to an answer, but it's for Windows7. Maybe it will get you on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Way too late but `Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager/Admin::112 (Event ID)` seems to track HDMI connected.

> Only tested on Microsoft Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for myself and wanted to share it here even though this thread is so old. Krishnakanth was close; `Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager/Admin` is the correct event log. In my experience with Windows 10, when I switch to a different monitor using an HDMI switch, the log registers Event ID 100 to show that the DeviceSetupManager service has started working. It then iterates through connected devices and issues Event ID 112 for each device. This is not useful, however, because I don't think Event ID 112 really distinguishes whether a device is actually on and connected. I think it only shows that the device is configured in Device Manager. After scanning all of the devices, the log registers Event 101 to show that it is finished.

Accordingly, what you can do is use a Scheduled Task to watch for `Microsoft-Windows-DeviceSetupManager/Admin::100 (Event ID)` and then run a simple PowerShell script to check the connected monitors:

```
# Get all PnP devices that are monitors
$monitors = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PnPEntity | Where-Object {$_.Service -eq 'monitor'}

# Display the PNPDeviceID for each monitor
foreach ($monitor in $monitors) {
    Write-Output "PNPDeviceID: $($monitor.PNPDeviceID)"
    }
```

This outputs a unique ID for all of the connected monitors, which can be used to carry out whatever operation you have in mind.

One catch: because the DeviceSetupManager takes a while to complete, this method cannot perfectly handle situations where a monitor is rapidly unplugged and plugged in again. Event ID 100 only triggers once and cannot trigger again until Event ID 101 is given about 1 minute later (depending on how many devices it must check). One potential workaround is to watch for Event 101 instead, which means that your script will not trigger right away but will wait until DeviceSetupManager is done.